# Mock class in a signed Jar file with Mockito

Tags: testing, mocking, eclipse-rcp, mockito

I'm trying to partially mock a class from a signed Jar file (actually, the target class is in the Eclipse API).

Is there any way to do that with Mockito? I tried out several workarounds, but the result is always something like this:

```
org.mockito.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: 
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
  ...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  ...
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException:
    class "org.eclipse.jdt.launching.AbstractJavaLaunchConfigurationDelegate$$
           FastClassByMockitoWithCGLIB$$6e308a80"'s
    signer information does not match signer information of other classes
    in the same package
    ...
```

A Bit of Googling showed me that [PowerMock might help me](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/Motivation#Using_a_3rd_party_or_legacy_framework), but I would like to avoid introducing a new dependency for my project.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe CGLIB had been tweaked to support signed packages, but there might be some issues.
Could you make a simple project, that demonstrate the problem and open an issue on the mockito project ?

Are you running the mocks inside OSGI ?

Brice

Comment: Thx for the effort, Brice. Basically I'm developing an Eclipse plugin and done something like this: `val delegate = spy(new MySimpleLaunchDelegate); doReturn(Array("a", "b")).when(delegate).getClasspath(config)`. Gonna try to reproduce the issue with a minimal example.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm not familiar with signed jars. But could you check the value of the ProtectionDomain of the `AbstractJavaLaunchConfigurationDelegate` and the class of the mock ? Eventually this discussion can continue on the Mockito issue :)

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue with several approaches (even mixing Scala/Java code), but I was unable to do it. It must have been a configuration issue from my side. All of the Mockito versions were running perfectly, even the older one I used originally (1.8.5). Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: @rlegendi OK, happy mocking then ;)